# Concise case changing code

Tags: code-golf, string

Create the shortest program that given an input string it outputs the opposite-cased string. For example if I pass the string `"HeLlO"` the program should output `"hElLo"`.

Of course, neither aggregate functions can be used, nor framework functions like `toupper()` or `tolower()`. Any language is welcome.

Comment: Do I have to handle characters that aren't letters or spaces?

Comment: Those are irrelevant

Comment: @defmx what about uppercase numbers like `^`?

Comment: Does the program have to handle letters other than `A-Za-z`? For example, what should the program output for `ёЖик уКраЇнА`?

Comment: Can you define "*aggregate function*" in the context of this question?

Comment: @PeterOlson Oh I only considered the latin alphabet for this exercise, I think this would be another puzzle

Comment: You still need to answer DigitalTrauma's question. (Does "*aggregate function*" mean `fold`?) And you still need to fully answer Peter Olson's question; the Latin alphabet covers [over a thousand Unicode code points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode).

Comment: @PeterTaylor I presume defmx means the Basic Latin alphabet (U+0041 to U+005A and U+0061 to U+007A).

Comment: Can I assume that only A-Za-z will be input?

Answer (score 14):

## Bash shell, 16 characters

```
tr A-Za-z a-zA-Z
```

Sample runs:

```
llama@llama:~$ tr A-Za-z a-zA-Z
ThIs is a TeSt!
tHiS IS A tEsT!
llama@llama:~$ echo 'Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange' | tr A-Za-z a-zA-Z
pROGRAMMING pUZZLES & cODE gOLF sTACK eXCHANGE
```

It works in a file, too (of course):

```
llama@llama:~$ echo 'tr A-Za-z a-zA-Z' > swapcase.sh
llama@llama:~$ echo 'This is a test!' | bash swapcase.sh
tHIS IS A TEST!
```

Comment: I don't think anybody could possibly get their program any shorter than this

Comment: @ThreeFx you are right it is very short, however this question comes to my mind: is it really a program? I think this only invokes a program; I'm not disqualifying the idea, just help me get this clear.

Comment: @defmx It is indeed a Bash program; I suppose you could think of `tr` as a function in other languages. (You could even say that most small shell scripts are kind of just a lot of tiny scripts glued together to make a bigger script. :P) It runs as an executable if you add a `#!/bin/bash` to the beginning of the `swapcase.sh` file, so it is a program. In fact, I could even say that this is a 13-character program in `tr`, but that would be stretching it :)

Comment: @Doorknob Excellent, yes we could say it is a program in tr because it is the interpreter, cool!

Comment: `echo ${1~~}` for 11 chars, but I suppose this [undocumented feature](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2265268/2113226) might counts as "framework functions"

Answer (score 14):

## CJam - 5

```
q32f^
```

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

Let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Wow, very nice! This seems to strip spaces and non-alphabetic characters, however.

Comment: @Doorknob well, it xor's everything with 32, space becomes NUL, but in my understanding, non-alphabetic characters are irrelevant

Answer (score 6):

## C, 67 chars

```
main(c,d){while(~(c=getchar()))d=c|32,putchar(d>96&&d<123?c^32:c);}
```

Input/output via STDIN/STDOUT:

```
$ ./swapcase <<< "HELLO world!"
hello WORLD!
$
```

---

## C, 41 chars

```
main(){while(putchar(getchar()^32)<127);}
```

If we strictly only care about alphabetical letters.

```
$ printf %s {a..z} {A..Z} | ./swapcase
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz$ 
$
```

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, 16 (17 counting -p flag as 1)

```
y/A-Za-z/a-zA-Z/
```

Fundamentally the same as the sh solution. The only room for golfing is using the `y` synonym for `tr`.

I'd like to protest that all of these solutions are only correct for ASCII, though. I'd like to see someone produce a solution that's correct for Unicode 7.0, without using library functions or external data :-P

Comment: That's evil.  Post it as a challenege ;-)  If someone did that, you'd probably see everyone starting off with the same long Chinese-character filled string to cram the data in once someone makes it :)  Not all letters have a round-trip case conversion ( lc(uc(lc('ẞ'))) -> 'ss' (not ß), for instance).

Comment: @guifa I'll investigate. Going to see whether (IMO) the amount of information contained in the case mappings is "reasonable" for a challenge. If so, I'll write it.

Comment: To be honest, it will be too much. You'd need to know which characters have upper or lower versions which at two bits per character you're at ~16KB total just for masking whether the transformation can happen. Then you'll need 1-4 bytes to express the transformation per letter that can transform. I'd try limiting it to, say, just particular Latin code tables to make it feasible without coding in actual data compression

Comment: @guifa I'm optimistic that cleverness can get it down to perhaps 2kB without algorithms like gzip. Setting out to prove it :)

Comment: I've got some ideas on possible ways, given there's an uneven distribution. It'll be interesting to see people's tactics for sure.

Comment: **This is a polyglot** - it's also a valid sed script which does the same thing!

Answer (score 5):

### Vim, 2

```
~G
```

In Normal mode, with the cursor on the first line, and with `'tildeop'` set, this command will swap the case of every character in the current buffer. This probably shouldn't count, but it's also very likely the fewest number of characters one need type to perform the operation in question, so I figured I'd share.

Comment: How about `norm gg~G` (9 chars) as a valid statement in VimL?

Answer (score 3):

## Marbelous - 249

```
00 @0 00 @1
&2 &0 // &0
.. /\ @0 \/
]] !! 0A
RR .. \\ &2
=0 \\ 00
&2 @1 /\
:R
}0 .. 00 @2
=A .. &1 +Z @3
@0 .. {0 +U //
.. /\ .. &0
>Z {0 >Z @4
-Z .. -Z 
>T @2 >Z
-U .. -Z
<Q @3 >Q
+Z .. -S
+Z .. <Q &0
+R @4 +Z \/
\\ .. +S @0
.. &2 // &1
.. {0 .. \/
```

Comment: Don't forget to count newlines as characters, however, if you take out the spaces (which marbelous supports) you can get it down to 211 bytes, including newlines.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 109 bytes

```
import sys
s=''
for c in sys.argv[1]:
  n=ord(c)
  if 64<n<91:n+=32
  elif 96<n<123:n-=32
  s+=chr(n)
print s
```

Comment: Would appending to a string and `print`ing it at the end instead of all the messy `sys` stuff save any characters?

Comment: @Doorknob 2 chars is 2 chars!

Comment: Heh, well at least it's shorter! Couldn't you remove the `,sys` on the first line now?

Comment: @Doorknob newp, need it for argv.

Comment: Oh, right. Actually, you could just use `input()` instead (in Python 3), which is shorter and also removes the need for `sys`. (you would have to add parentheses for `print`, but you would save many more characters)

Comment: @Doorknob By my estimation it would shave off another 2 chars, but I don't have etiher Python 3 installed or the gumption to do so. :P

Comment: Wouldn't it save 7? -4 for `sys.argv[1]` to `input()`, -4 for removing `,sys`, and +1 for adding parentheses on the `print s` line.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, why do you even need to import `string`? You're not using anything in it (`ord` and `chr` are builtins).

Comment: I'm fairly new to python, and when I started I swear `ord()` didn't work until I imported `string`. `:I`

Answer (score 2):

## Cobra - 100 (or 81)

```
class P
    def main
        for c in Console.readLine,Console.write(if(c.isLetter,((c to int)^32)to char,c))
```

If only letters matter

```
class P
    def main
        for c as int in Console.readLine,Console.write((c^32)to char)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge 93 - 45

```
>~:55+-#v_@>
_v#`g19:<] ^,-g29
 >92g+,    ^
```

Terminates when a NL is entered.

Answer (score 2):

## Python - 44

```
print''.join(chr(ord(c)^32)for c in input())
```

The program expects an input string quotes `"HeLLo"`, which should be legit. [Using Python 3](http://ideone.com/6t8Pni) we can easily pass the string without quotes like `HeLLo` at the cost of two more characters for the `print`-brackets.

Comment: [Two bytes shorter as a lambda](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PycxNyklUaHCSklJLys/M08jOaNII78oRSNTM87YSDMtv0ghUyEzT6FC8/9/AA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 68

```
import sys
print''.join(chr((ord(l)-33)%64+65) for l in sys.argv[1])
```

Simple python script featuring no ifs or elses.

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol - 25

```
forall s[s/1: s/1 xor 32]
```

Usage example (in Rebol console):

```
>> ;; s is the input string

>> s: "HeLlO"
== "HeLlO"

>> forall s [s/1: s/1 xor 32]
== #"o"

>> s
== "hElLo"
    
>> forall s [s/1: s/1 xor 32] 
== #"O"

>> s
== "HeLlO"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 3 bytes

```
c^H
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=Y15I&input=IkhlTGxPIg==)

XORs (`^`) the charcode (`c`) of each character with 32 (`H`).

Answer (score 0):

## Lua - 78

```
while""do a=io.read(1)b=a<']'and 32 or-32 io.write(string.char(a:byte()+b))end
```

Nothing special, and it ups any character smaller ']' and downs any one larger.

Answer (score 0):

## CoffeeScript - 85 (or <strike>77</strike> 67)

Since non-alphabetic characters don't matter:

```
f=(x)->x.split('').map((c)->String.fromCharCode((c.charCodeAt(0)-33)%64+65)).join('')
```

Discarding whitespace and other non-alphabetic characters:

```
f=(x)->x.split('').map((c)->String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0)^32)).join('')
```

Even shorter:

```
f=(x)->(String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0)^32)for c in x).join('')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure - 182 chars

I'm a Clojure newbie. Golfed:

```
(defn b[i x y](if(and(> i x)(< i y)) true false))(print(apply str(map #(let[i(int %)](if(b i 64 92)(char (+ i 32))(if(b i 96 123)(char (+ i -32)) %))) (first *command-line-args*))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defn b[i x y] (if (and(> i x)(< i y)) true false))
(print (apply str (map 
        #(let [i (int %)] (if (b i 64 92) 
                             (char (+ i 32)) 
                             (if (b i 96 123) (char (+ i -32)) %))) 
        (first *command-line-args*))))
```