# Swap letter cases

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a non‑empty string containing only printable ASCII (codepoints 0x20 to 0x7E), write the **shortest program or function** that swaps the cases of `A-Z` and `a-z`.

- If a character is in `[A-Z]`, convert it to its lowercase version.
- If a character is in `[a-z]`, convert it to its uppercase version.
- Otherwise, leave the character alone.

#### Test Cases

| input | output |
| --- | --- |
| `abc` | `ABC` |
| `ABC` | `abc` |
| `Mixed Case` | `mIXED cASE` |
| `1234` | `1234` |
| `123#$%hIjK456` | `123#$%HiJk456` |

Comment: I don't consider this a dup of the other case swapping challenges because the others (such as https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36802/77309) are X-without-Y challenges, which this isn't.

Comment: I would consider it a dupe, but I closed the other question instead since its restrictions are really unclear, and this is clearly the higher quality question.

Answer (score 10):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 2 bytes

```
Yo
```

Try it at [MATL online](https://matl.io/?code=Yo&inputs=%27M1xed+Cas3%27&version=22.8.0)!

Comment: `Yo!!` also works and is perhaps more _idiomatic_

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
lambda s:[chr(ord(c)^32*c.isalpha())for c in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKjo5o0gjvyhFI1kzzthIK1kvszgxpyAjUUNTMy2/SCFZITNPoTj2f0FRZl6JRpqGumOiU5Jzsrqm5n8A)

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKjexQAPKSbZKzijSyC9K0UjWjDM20krWyyxOzCnISNTQ1NQp1vxfUJSZV6KRpqHumOiU5Jysrqn5HwA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: [47 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYKjo5o0gjvyhFI1kzzthIK1kvszgxpyAjUUNTMy2/SCFZITNPoTj2f0FRZl6JRpqGumOiU5Jzsrqm5n8A "Python 3 – Try It Online") if returning a list is fine (since you used `map` originally)

Comment: @enzo Nice trick there multiplying 32 by c.isalpha() to make it zero.

Answer (score 6):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 40 bytes

```c
f(char*s){if(*s^=isalpha(*s)/32)f(s+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9dT4MwFIav4VecVEnagXGwsQuRGJwz4kdiwo0JYlIrlaogoVwsIf3t2OLM4q7ek@c9H@9hJ@@MjSPHrKLdTJJBcDyTL7GQ9KutqK7J6SIgHEvXJ5EaRdNDTUWDCQy2ZYagL2XPqCxlHoSrIg@KSSE2DdaA6CtDHqDkco2UNxFTamKMHXkQ2/IN1nqJMer0aXMFLMk2f74fLJbGmXTPjo6dKv24W4arnanBjbj9NEDZlops2@LfHWCTWuhE80jLOYQRuK6YPrA43ucXRT4vSKRp2@kRjpEjwZHPjV4v@47V7WGzB/@AXxCI9Rm4APSYZBmCM0DXSXqPDhp/zyhbjT8)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>45</s></sup> 42 bytes

```c
f(char*s){if(*s^=isalpha(*s)?32:0)f(s+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9dT4MwFIav4VecVEnagQljYxdDsuCcET8SE25MEJNaqVQFCeXChPS3Y4szi7t6T573fLyHnb0xNo4cs4p2M0kGwfFMPsdC0s@2oromm0Ww9gnH0p2TSI2i6aGmosEEBtsyY9CXsmdUljIPwlWRB8WkEJsGa0D0hSEPUHKxRcqbiCk1Mcae3Ivv8hW2eokx6vRxdwksyXZ//jxYLI0z6YGdnDpV@n67DFd7U4NrcfNhgLItFdm2xb86wCa10In8SMs5hBG4rpg@sDg@5BdF7hck0rTt9AjHyJHgyKdGr5d9x@r2uNmDf2BeEIj1GdgAekiyDMEa0FWS3qGjxt8zylbjDw)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 12 bytes

```python
str.swapcase
```

[Attempt This Online! (Python 3)](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY_BSgMxEIbveYqBKklgu6CtIkKFWgtW6amXHhZh3Wbp6DY7JCm2z-Kll3ryBfoofZtODD0ayDD58vEP8_1D27Bs7W5fwwCK_TrU3btfH1zuv0qqSm8SOh5wRa0L4LdeiLp10KA1gDaC3IcF2nsBfNBSBmZDnBYN_nJISueeGgxKQvcBpD6bLHHNnaGmrIySRWFlBpJrUlIO1_8VcmiD-hMHUCuO0xmw7VR6aJ0W2B3fyvcqjh8-jgTf2DIRU9yYBYx400hWk_n4CarhbCyurgvb60eYOga9zsXlcvLx2r-5TTyCZ3z5ZJDGnAA)
[Attempt This Online! (Python 2)](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY_BagIxEIbveYqBtiQL60LVSilYsFbQlp566WERtmsWp12zQxJRn8WLF-nFm0_j23TS1KOBTIYvH_8k2x_a-Hlj2rt9BX3I90tfte4PztvMrQoqC6cjOh1xQY314DZOiKqxUKPRgCaAzPkZmgcBvNBQCnpNnBYMvrJIKskc1eiVhNYjyORsssQ1s5rqotRK5rmRKUiuUYk5XC8rZNF49Sf2oVIcl6T_ZxKfvjtNi88yDB48DQXv0DIRb7jWMxjyHwNZTD5Gz1AO3kfitp2bTjfA2DHoXF3fzCdfr927XuQBjPHlm0Ec8ws)

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
rQ2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72koLIkY8FmZSXPvILSEiulQCX_0hIwa2lpSZquxeKiQCMIa0m2baArhLngpqFSYlKyEpeSo5MzkPTNrEhNUXBOLE4FcgyNYvKMTcAMY2UV1QzPLG8TUzOocQA)

```
 Q    # input
r 2   # swapcase
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

*-5 thanks to [@ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn)*

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/./g,c=>c[`to${c<{}?'Low':'Upp'}erCase`]())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1q5Yryi1ICcxOVVDX08/XSfZ1i45OqEkX6U62aa61l7dJ79c3Uo9tKBAvTa1yDmxODUhVkNT839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahlJiUrKSpqYCAujrKzg6OXOhKQMKYSgDakVX5ptZkZqiALIMqhqoLNczwtVFIdkx2BVdtaGRsQmKqUDVIDEs6pRVVDM8s7xNTM1AGiDqgGIemV7ZQLH/AA)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 45 bytes

*-6 thanks to [@ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn)*

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(c=>c^32*(c>>6&--c%32<26))+""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxBC4IwGMbxe59irIytUGmapxTUhCw6dekUrDlLUyeuom9vk4LIeo9/fs@b0zuVrMnqq16JhLep20rXC25pyhsksVHSGjHXYweLTBDzPGes60yzyII4GE8hbJmopCi4UYgTShGkRwYxBp8zTeAH4aDHVPphatpn2@zBExBSyd9asTLeR0vA/F3U1zNi2V9fle7aHzccaec439hzpxu8nGqrbH1RrX0C)

Comment: why not `/./g` (instead of `/[a-z]/gi`) for es6?

Comment: shorter for node.js: `s=>Buffer(s).map(c=>c^32*(c>>6&--c%32<26))+''`

Comment: [42](https://tio.run/##bcxBC4IwGMbxe59irIyNUGmaNwU1IYtOXToFa87S1Imr6NuvSUFkvcc/v@ct6Z1K1hXt1WxExlXuK@kH0S3PeYcktmraIuYH7IDY1HOnzHCISTxsEzyDUDHRSFFxqxInlCNIjwxiDD5n2yCM4tGA6fTD9HTItsWDZyCmkr@1ZnW6T5aAhbtkqOfEcb@@at23P248Mc5puXEXXj94Od1Wxfqim3oC)

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 20 bytes

```
{`c$(_x)-32*~"a{"'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pOSFbRiK/Q1DU20qpTSqxWUq+o5eJKU0pMSlYCUo5OziDKN7MiNUXBObE4FcQzNDI2gdLKKqoZnlneJqZmDnWJVY5RSgCXthWz)

Lowercase the entire string using the builtin `_` and then subtract 32 from those that were already lowercase to make them uppercase.

```
{`c$(_x)-32*~"a{"'x}    x: string
             "a{"'x     for each char c in x, -1 if c<'a', 0 if 'a'<=c<'{',
                        1 if '{'<=c
         32*~           boolean not times 32; gives 32 for lowercase in input
    (_x)                lowercase version of x
        -               subtract to uppercase the lowercase
 `c$                    convert the result of arithmetic back to char type
```

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 31 bytes

```r
\(s)chartr("a-zA-Z","A-Za-z",s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhb7YzSKNZMzEotKijSUEnWrHHWjlHSUgCSQraRTrAlRdbMiDSiblKykqayga6fg6OTMBRQAUlABoBRIwDezIjVFwTmxOBUqnusZ4eqikOwY7AqSNjQyNoFKgJhQIWUV1QzPLG8TUzOEHFDMI9MrGygGsX_BAggNAA)

Comment: Another day, another R function I've never seen before!

Answer (score 5):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 2 bytes

```
V~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P6zu///EpOQURydnF0UHZRUA)

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + coreutils, 16 bytes

Exactly what `tr` is for.

```bash
tr A-Za-z a-zA-Z
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8G21OSMfAV1QyNjZRXVDM8sbxNTM3WFmqWlJWm6FhtKihQcdaMSdasUgBjIgggvgFJQGgA)

Comment: [11 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/270293/119544). -5 bytes by using the Bash `~~` operator instead of `tr` translate method.

Comment: @vengy your answer is fundamentally different enough to not be a modification of this one

Answer (score 5):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 11 bytes

The `~~` operator in Bash can be used to [toggle the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash) of all characters in a string.

```bash
echo ${1~~}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19Bpdqwrq72////hkbGyiqqGZ5Z3iamZgA)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this breaks at least one standard loophole.

Comment: If you introduce input that's not part of the question, you have to include it in the answer. Then it is pretty much a copy of my answer.

Comment: @Neil The answer has been updated to close any standard loophole and is now 
 shorter using the `~~` operator instead of the longer `tr` method. Thanks.

Comment: You're still reading input from the predefined variable `$s` instead of, say, an argument `$1` which would work just as well for the same byte count and has the advantage of being an acceptable input format.

Comment: @Neil Nice! Thanks for the tip about using `$1` instead of `$s`. Works great now and occupies the same number of bytes too.

Answer (score 4):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 59 bytes

```python
N
Count i while _ {
Write _+_/65*(90/_-_/97*(122/_))*32
N
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/9@Pyzm/NK9EIVOhPCMzJ1UhXqGaK7woswTI0o7XNzPV0rA00I/Xjde3NNfSMDQy0o/X1NQyNuLy46r9/9/QyFhZxSGhTiHRMSmyKgoA)

#### Explanation

Here's a slightly de-obfuscated version:

```python
N
Count i while _ {
  Write _ + (_/65)*(90/_)*32 - (_/97)*(122/_)*32
  N
}
```

`N` reads a character of input and stores its ASCII code in the accumulator.

`Count i while _` loops while the accumulator's value is nonzero. After the end of input (including an implicit trailing newline), `N` returns zero, so this loops over the entire input and then halts.

*Acc!!* doesn't have comparison operators, so we use integer division to determine what range a character code is in:

| _/65 | 90/_ | _/97 | 122/_ | Range |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | >= 1 | 0 | >= 1 | _ < A |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | A ≤ _ ≤ Z |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | Z < _ < a |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | a ≤ _ ≤ z |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | z < _ |

Multiplying the first two tells us the character is uppercase, in which case we add 32 to make it lowercase. Multiplying the second two tells us the character is lowercase, in which case we subtract 32 to make it uppercase. We then `Write` out the modified character and read another one with `N`.

For the golfed version, we pull the common factor of 32 out of both products, and then observe that `_/65` can only ever be 0 or 1, and it's only 0 when we don't want to modify the character, so it can be pulled out as well.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
3!:12"+~'`'&I.
```

NOTE: fails on ATO's older J but works in j9.4.2

*-9 thanks to ovs!!*

*-2 thanks to Bubbler for a very nice refinement!*

The basic clever idea is due to ovs.   The idea to simplify it using "insert before" to get the upper/lower flags `` '`'&I. `` is due to Bubbler.

- `3!:12` is the J verb for changing case -- a 0 left arg makes it downcase and a 1 makes it upcase.  We add `"+` to change the rank and make it work on atoms.
- `` ~'`'&I. `` Returns a boolean array with zeros where the input is less than `` ` `` (lowercase), and ones elsewhere (uppercase).
- That boolean array, in its entirety, is the left arg to `3!:12`, and the original input is the right arg.  Since we are operating on atoms, it flips the case of each letter.

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 24 bytes

```
g`tolower@.(=g=.toupper)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxIz2hJD8nvzy1yEFPwzbdVq8kv7SgILVIEyK9VZMrNTkjXyFNQd03syI1RcE5sThVHSK3YAGEBgA)

*-1 thanks to ovs for this variant using agenda!*

This showcases an interesting fact about agenda, which is that if you provide it a list of integers, it runs on each on separately, returning a list of results.

So it applies 'tolower' to every uppercase letter, and `toupper` to every lowercase one.

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>27</s> 25 bytes (original)

```
(=0{g)`(g=.3!:12"{~&0 1)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxU8PWoDpdM0Ej3VbPWNHK0Eipuk7NQMFQsxYif9NVk8vPSU8hJCOzWCG1qCi_qFghP0_BMcRfvVjBSyGptEShPL8oGyyYZalnomekx5WanJGvkKag7ptZkZqi4JxYnKoOMWzBAggNAA) (NOTE: fails on ATO's older J but works in j9.4.2)

[29 byte variant that works on ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxV8PWoDpdM0Ej3VavJD8nvzy1SMeqJL-0oCC1SLMWomarJldqcka-QpqCum9mRWqKgnNicao6RG7BAggNAA):

```
(=0{g)`(g=.tolower,:toupper)}
```

The variant is clearer for the explanation anyway:

- `` (...)`(...)} `` A single application of the rarely used [Item Amend](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d530n.htm).
- `g=.tolower,:toupper` Construct all lowercase and all uppercase versions of the input:

  ```
  mixed case
  MIXED CASE
  ```
- `=0{g` Boolean vector showing where the input is lowercase:

  ```
  0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
  ```
- Item amend then takes from the uppercase version at each 1 index, and from the lowercase version at each 0 index.

Comment: Using *Agenda* gets close for a variant working on older versions: [26](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxKz2hJD8nvzy1yEFPwzbdVq8kv7SgILVIU8kAomCrJldqcka-QpqCum9mRWqKgnNicao6RG7BAggNAA). Actually, omitting the `"0` still works, so it's 24. Didn't know Agenda worked that way.

Comment: And I think `(=0&g)(g=.3!:12"+)]` works. ... and `q~]=0&q=.3!:12"+`

Comment: oh my... `q~]=0&q=.3!:12"+` is brilliant

Comment: 14 bytes: ``3!:12"+~'`'&I.`` - toupper for characters of `a` or higher, tolower otherwise.

Comment: @Bubbler That is very nice use of insert before.

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 1 byte

```
¯
```

[Try it on Uiua pad!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__wq8iYWJjIgrCryJBQkMiCsKvIk1peGVkIENhc2UiCsKvIjEyMzQiCsKvIjEyMyMkJWhJaks0NTYiCg==)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 14 bytes

```perl
s/\pL/$&^$"/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YP6bAR19FLU5FST899f//xKTkFEcnZ5d/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 24 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @akamayu and another -1 thanks to @ngn!

ngn/K has a builtin for converting to lower case (`_`), but none for converting to uppercase, so there has to be some sort of codepoint arithmetic involved.

```
`c$32/|(0/2\1-"A[a{"')'\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs0pIVjE20q/RMNA3ijHUVXKMTqxWUtdUj+HiSlNKTEpWAlKOTs4gyjezIjVFwTmxOBXEMzQyNoHSyiqqGZ5Z3iamZkoAJ9wTeA==)

Comment: From the first alternative, by changing `-1+` to `1-` and `-32` to `+32`, we have ``{`c$x+32*a*2!a:1-"A[a{"'x}``, saving a byte.

Comment: building up on this solution: you can save a couple more bytes by encoding the index in binary and multiplying its bits together: ```{`c$x-32*/2\" A[a{"'x}``` - here uppercase and lowercase correspond to 1 and 3, and they happen to be the only valid indices whose product of bits is 1

Comment: @ngn I don't think that works. We need to add 32 for uppercase letters, but `32*/2\...` is never negative.

Comment: oops.. i was using a bad test. sorry

Comment: just one byte shorter: ``` `c${x+32*0/2\1-"A[a{"'x}' ``` (and hopefully correct this time)

Comment: @ngn yes that works, thanks. was able to get rid of another byte by going full tacit

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 71 bytes

```
=LET(c,MID(A1,ROW(A:A),1),d,LOWER(c),CONCAT(IF(EXACT(c,d),UPPER(c),d)))
```

Input is in the cell `A1`. Output is wherever the formula is. I feel like there should be a shorter way to do this but Excel is limited in its case-switching functions.

The `LET()` function allows you to define variable as a `name,value` pair. This saves us bytes by letting us reference data by a shorter name.

- `c,MID(A1,ROW(A:A),1)` breaks the input into individual characters. In the latest versions of Excel, `ROW(A:A)` will have a max value of 2^20 and the characters in a cell are limited to 2^15 so this will cover all cases.
- `d,LOWER(c)` converts each character into its lowercase regardless of how it started.
- `CONCAT(IF(EXACT(c,d),UPPER(c),d))` checks each original character to see if it matches the lowercase version and, if it does, returns the uppercase version. Otherwise, it returns the lowercase. We have to use `EXACT()` because `c=d` is case-insensitive. The `CONCAT()` parts just re-combines all those individual characters into a single string.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, 64 bytes

```java
s->{for(var c:s)System.out.print(c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?c^=32:c);}
```

Input as a character-array; output is printed directly to STDOUT.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZZFZQ4JAEIDf/RUTlUEq5UWJipldZtpht0etCyqoYOx6pfTXaVH0ofZhdmZn9pvLQGMUMdSei/uIECgj3ZwHAHSTanYbYQ0qngkwtnQVMI@7yK41gAhp9uoEmCAUUR1DBUzIuiSizNuWzY@RDVgmQnVGqDYQrREVhzZj8liREkGcSUUXWElJTIvG4jnczMZjMhbSjpv2kMNRq8@QPnmZecDq4quUMTq1BhJWNa0zUY3QAiIayGBqE1iHzTnUwlyYy58WmCzrU00FL4wZLGtidW3v7HaLRimRlJhdq9cbzY9PpsFWnWOu4B4v7IfCEfHg0PuSlI6OU3I6k1VyJ4x6dn5xeVW8Lt2UK7d39w/Vx6fnl9e3d5/Ckqtau9PVjV5/YFrDL5vQ0XgynX3PF84P5/hNAPwb0rqfECfXKbcctXdMEW9cIrUKbBV520YzXtiE/EX1Td73Oct9Oe4v)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                  // Method with character-array parameter and no return
  for(var c:s)        //  Loop over the characters of the input:
    System.out.print( //   Print:
      c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?
                      //    If the character is a letter:
       c^=32          //     Invert its case by XOR-ing the codepoint by 32 (the `^=`
                      //     instead of `^` is so it'll remain a character instead of
                      //     becoming an integer)
      :               //    Else (it's not a letter):
       c);}           //     Print the character as is
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), <s>16</s>, 12 bytes

```
m$TL?.TU~<iU
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNxczcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRMDS0pI0XYt1aba5KiE-9nohoXU2maEQwZumuYmZeQq2XAoKBcEKKgppCkrGFi-XLLQw9c1MPbzENzv7cPfhZZeXVuQbGPimFhcXe7h4XF2pBNG8YAGEBgA)

*Thanks to [Bubbler's comment on a different post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/270235/swap-letter-cases#comment586029_270259) for helping me realize how to take 4 bytes off*

### Explanation

This is really simple. `m` maps across a string `iU` checks if a character is uppercase, `TU` makes a character uppercase `TL` makes it lowercase.

## Using parsers, 22 bytes

```
gk$my$(TL<pU)#|(TU<hd)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNxczcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRMDS0pI0XYsdabbp2Sq5lSoaIT42BaGayjUaIaE2GSmaEOmbprmJmXkKtlwKCgXBCioKaQpKxhYvlyy0MPXNTD28xDc7-3D34WWXl1bkGxj4phYXF3u4eFxdqQTRvGABhAYA)

## Reflection

<s>It's really weird that the main answer uses basically no function composition, and the only infix function it uses is function application, especially considering it uses 6 functions in total.  However the `l3` is still glue, and is clearly costing more than it should.</s> I golfed away the `l3` now, which is good.

The parser version is never going to be competitive for this challenge, but I did it anyway to get practice with that part of the library. 22 bytes is not awful, I don't think, but it could probably be improved.

- A case swap builtin would probably be good. It seems weird and niche, but I can see how this is can actually be useful in odd ways, and apparently both Vyxal and Python have it as builtins.
- `l3 iF` is probably worth having, plus a version that only lifts over the first two arguments.
- `l3` could have an infix version. Even at 3 bytes, this would save bytes.
- The `tr` function that I see other people using seems like it could be helpful in general, although it's unlikely it would ever be the way to go for this answer. [Best case scenario is 15 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNp8zcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRABXZl5aZkWRgqmClooqlwaQ0LTlUijx9LWx8QXiqoKlpSVpuhYb02zPbbKxOzcJqODcJCBjE0T8pmluYmaeAlCLQkGwgopCmoKSscXLJQstTH0zUw8v8c3OPtx9eNnlpRX5Bga-qcXFxR4uHldXKkE0L1gAoQE).
- Maybe something that combines `gk` and `gMy` would be useful. "Apply this parser as many times as it takes to finish the string".
- A shortcut for `fm hd`, parse a character and apply a function, would probably be good.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 1 byte

```
N
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJOIiwiIiwiYUJcbkNkIiwiMy40LjIiXQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## TypeScript’s type system, 141 bytes

141 bytes with capitalization builtins:

```typescript
type G<C,U=Uppercase<C>,L=Lowercase<C>>=U extends L?C:C extends U?L:U
type F<S,O>=S extends`${infer C}${infer S}`?F<S,`${O&string}${G<C>}`>:O
```

186 bytes no builtins:

```typescript
type F<S,O>=S extends`${infer C}${infer S}`?F<S,`${O&string}${"aAabBbcCcdDdeEefFfgGghHhiIijJjkKklLlmMmnNnoOopPpqQqrRrsSstTtuUuvVvwWwxXxyYyzZz"extends`${any}${C}${infer c}${any}`?c:C}`>:O
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog APL)](https://www.dyalog.com/products.htm), <sup><s>13</s></sup> 12 bytes

```
⊢⎕C¨⍨¯1*⎕C≠⊢
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qpTIxJz89PrEgZ8EqK7_E3NTigsTk1KWlJWm6FrsedS161DfV-dCKR70rDq031AJxHnUuAApDFNyscnvUNuFRb5_Ro65moGRwkDOQDPHwDObiAjKAcm7qiUnJ6nCOo5MzguObWZGaouCcWJyKEDM0MjZB4SmrqGZ4ZnmbmJqpc1m55qWgOXHBAggNAA)

```
⊢⎕C¨⍨¯1*⎕C≠⊢­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
           ⊢  # ‎⁡input
          ≠   # ‎⁢not equal to (vectorized)
        ⎕C    # ‎⁣lowercase version
     ¯1*      # ‎⁤-1 ^ x (convert 0 to 1, 1 to -1)
 ⎕C¨⍨         # ‎⁢⁡convert to uppercase where 1 and lowercase where -1
⊢             # ‎⁢⁢on input
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 1 byte

```apl
-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X/e/26O2CY96@4wfdTU/6tn7qG9qcJAzkAzx8Az@76aemJSszuWm7ujkDKJ8MytSUxScE4tTQTxDI2MTKK2soprhmeVtYmqmDgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>64</s> 58 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler).*

```hs
import Data.Char
f s=[last(toUpper:[toLower|c<'a'])c|c<-s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xDoIwFEX3fsVL1QCJkqjoYGRQXIwyOpEOTyyhCrRpX6KD/16JccE7nXuWU6N7yKbxXrVGW4IDEsZZjZZV4NKiQUch6Ysx0m4K0mf9lPZdbgMMRFT2MHPCk3TkIIUCOF5LzuC3KfDdPhv8XL3kDTJ0cqDni2XyL0bjSX28n5LVmoNgrEXV9Y0WTQ6hsaojiKGK4Bv3Hw)

I wish there were a more interesting solution but it probably looks like:

### 85 bytes

```hs
f s=[last$c:[toEnum$o-(signum$o-91)*32|64<o&&o<91||96<o&&o<123]|c<-s,o<-[fromEnum c]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY29DoIwHMR3nuIfRAIGTPiQBFMGJQ7G@AQNQ8UiKKWE1sSh715RXPCmu19ydzURD9q2WlcgMtwSIa1yiyU/dE9mcd8RzW1yaeCuolAlMeK2zVEaKJUmkw/CqFAl8oXHkY@rgbNPG8qi0JIKKSADDCa5lKYBP3lg7vb5LJ@bF71CTgSd4XE8/gcLa1kf76d4k5hQGAYjTTd@MNKfwemHppOwhsqF77l@Aw)

...Yeah. Gross. There's also:

### 98 bytes

```hs
f s=[last$c:[n|(Just n)<-[m]]|c<-s,m<-[lookup c$zip['a'..'z']['A'..'Z']++zip['A'..'Z']['a'..'z']]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BCoJAGITvPsWPGVuYQmUdwg7VqcIXaNnDtmmaqy39G4T47G0mRdic5psZmJRjHktpTAK4pJKjdsSClvVgd0cN5TD0aMFYLUIPR0UD8nrN7wqEU2WKEk58n1SEUbJ6uwNhrtsWX/xNGDM6Ro2wBAo2Pwrbgo9GYK/Wmw5H2SM@wYZj3InHk2nwH/Scfrq97IPZ3AZmWQXPyuaj4CqCgbplpQYfkiG05@YpEsnPaDyh1As)

I feel like this could get a whole lot better but I'm blanking.

Comment: 58: `import Data.Char;f s=[last(toUpper:[toLower|c<'a'])c|c<-s]`. There's a cool pointfree version `map$bool toUpper toLower=<<(<'a')` but costs an extra `import Data.Bool` so is slightly longer.

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY7NDsFAGEX38xQ3g5REGqWsVEJthC6txOLDNC39mc5MogvvPobY1N2dszk3I/0QRWFtXspaGWzJkB9npFgalSTRsAbtq1165EWmPtRPoRwHq4mjo5QfskZooxHhBE6XK2f4bQy@3sQdTvJW3BCTFh0dTGfhv@j1B9nuvg/nC44zYyXllWu4TwmGUuWVgY90hG/cvgE "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Bubbler For the pointfree version it's slightly shorter to just implement `bool` as an infix than to import it, but not enough to compete with the pointful versions.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ô∙!=¿δ!
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wlkcdMxVtD@0/t0Xx/3@lxKRkJS4lRydnIOmbWZGaouCcWJwK5BgaGZtAKGUV1QzPLG8TUzMlAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
ô       # Loop over the characters of the (implicit) input-string,
        # using the following 6 characters as inner code-block:
 ∙      #  Triplicate the current character
  !     #  Lowercase the top copy
   =    #  Pop the top two, and check whether they're still equal
    ¿   #  If they were equal (aka the character was lowercase, or not a letter):
     δ  #   Uppercase the character
    ¿   #  Else (it was an uppercase character)
     !  #   Lowercase the character instead
        # (after the loop, the entire stack is joined together and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r\lÈc^H
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=clxsyGNeSA&input=IjEyMyMkJWhJaks0NTYi)

Comment: Ugh, so obvious now! Nice

Answer (score 2):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 41 bytes

```
" @
,::4/*_
. _6  "
$*  %23
326#(
_ /
%#)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc5NTsMwEAXg/ZxiyI@UuA3GduLUFkWhXALYjFpYUAm1CLqghHB0zCSNAgtmZ@l97/l5vTm@bneHpxAibGDufSkFwTmSRYwgEYipNmC0jTMglJDGeYCyAvgTN2N@BJSlmgVazSJnogmgtBMZ0oPTaQYJTheB0IY4nkvbm4pnON8w8F4bibIjmAkkhUtXo@tHTicVT7VtKytLHRSzgvHiP4wTVhLE7zR2wNMMxxIAq/jD87xBxbjjlsx74iC5mp9c5BE52lsampgir0vlTlVhvXl4P35cr25u7@7xrIkTulC6Xrj2s/u6XF59718O2/3uLRSPPw)

Labyrinth doesn't have any built-ins related to letter case, and making multiple `if`-branches is incredibly wacky. Fortunately, it can be worked around using arithmetic operations. It also helps that it has the XOR operator, which means it suffices to identify letters vs. non-letters and apply XOR 32.

The code is kinda obfuscated by the use of "stack height" which saves 1 over pushing the first digit literally (`_` push 0 and then append a digit). Unobfuscated, the code does the following:

```
Big loop:
  ,::    getchar(x), dup twice [x x x]
         exit (turn left) on EOF(-1), continue (turn right) otherwise(positive)
  _64/*  [x x2]  make chars 63 or below into 0 -> x2
  _32%   [x x3]  modulo 32 -> x3 (letter iff 1 <= x3 <= 26)
  (_26/  [x x4]  decrement and divide by 26 -> x4 (letter iff x4 == 0)
  )_2%   [x b]   increment and modulo 2 -> b (0 or 1, 1 means letter)
  _32*$  [x']    x XOR 32 if letter, x otherwise
  .      []      putchar
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>52 bytes</s> 43 bytes

```scala
_.map(c=>if(c>'Z')c.toUpper else c.toLower)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9F4wU1rh9zEzDyFlNQ0hYzUnJx8DU0rhdC8zBIFW4VqLgWweFp-vpVCcElRZl66gq0dnKVQvbS0JE3X4qZ2vF5uYoFGsq1dZppGsp16lLpmsl5JfmhBQWqRQmpOcaoCiOuTX55apAnVsrcWaHZicXFqUYkG0HgNpcSkZCVNBVtbBSVHJ2clTTRZsBhYFqwOTdY3syI1RcE5sTgVqijXM8LVRSHZMdgVQ62hkbEJVBWEiSmvrKKa4ZnlbWJqhlAIFPPI9MoGi3HVQjyxYAGEBgA)

-5 bytes thanks to @movatica

-4 bytes thanks to @Bubbler

Comment: [47 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9F4wU1rh9zEzDyFlNQ0hYzUnJx8DU0rhdC8zBIFW4VqLgWweFp-vpVCcElRZl66gq0dnKVQvbS0JE3X4qZ-vF5uYoFGsq1dZppGsl5msU9-eWqRZrJeSX5oQUFqkUJqTnGqAogLkYBq21sLND-xuDi1qEQDaIWGUmJSspKmgq2tgpKjk7OSJposWAwsC1aHJuubWZGaouCcWJwKVZTrGeHqopDsGOyKodbQyNgEqgrCxJRXVlHN8MzyNjE1QygEinlkemWDxbhqIZ5YsABCAwA) using parenthesis instead of `then`

Comment: Change condition to `c>'Z'` to get 43 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### R, 48 bytes

```
\(s)gsub("([A-Z]*)([a-z]*)","\\L\\1\\U\\2",s,,T)
```

(T for `perl=TRUE`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 7 bytes

```
T`Ll`lL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JMEnJyHH5///xKRkLkcnZy7fzIrUFAXnxOJULkMjYxMQoayimuGZ5W1iagYA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Simply transliterates using the shortcuts for upper and lowercase letter ranges.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
⭆Ｓ⎇№αι↧ι↥ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaHjmFZSWQLgamjoKIalFeYlFlRrO@aVAZYk6CplAQZ/88tSi5MTiVA0QL7SgAM4DAuv//30zK1JTFJyBQlz/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 Ｓ          Input string
⭆           Map over characters and join
    α       Predefined variable uppercase ASCII
   №        Contains
     ι      Current character
  ⎇         If true then
        ι    Current character
       ↧     Lowercased
          ι  Else current character
         ↥   Uppercased
             Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 42 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{[char]($_-bxor32*($_-in"a".."z"))}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5RT4MwFIWfub@iwSJgYInb9G0JiEucxmjEB5NlWaB2A2Qw25IRGb8d2w1nsqfefufcc@623FHGE5rnLikZ7fBq0nQ4Ymu@N5o5SSK2sPDSjeuSjYZXakwLPdIHA/1Ht@22awHAs8DxLDOKiekg078LTPsA1CSB4kfwnNb0EwURp4pvZh/Te0T8cNrL18PRWAmH94QusJHMsqfxzW2vSfCQPn4pYION9shADWhY0Fo4CNN6S4mQNROElxIzyqtcyN8lXiFPmU7Q56FgabGWopuVaYF6DqDNX8Og4qLcvMSZjFsgT1ZoYUUI5VxFnyW4hH7/d0vruyxSvmOh9vZ3xdkiaC200P0C)

Takes an array of characters as input
Returns an array of characters

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
®c^H*Zè\l
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=rmNeSCpa6Fxs&input=IlRoZSBxdWljayAyMWEgQnJvd24gRm9YIg)

```
®c^H*Zè\l­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
®          # ‎⁡Map each character Z to:
 c         # ‎⁢  It transformed by passing its charcode through:
  ^        # ‎⁣    XOR with
   H       # ‎⁤      32
    *      # ‎⁢⁡      Multiplied by
     Zè    # ‎⁢⁢      Number of matches of the following regex in Z:
       \l  # ‎⁢⁣        [A-Za-z] (alphabetical)
```

Explanation created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands/2649a799300cbf3770e2db37ce177d4a19035a25) / [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable/blob/master/Info.txt), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
š
```

[Try it online in 05AB1E (legacy)](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6ML//5WUlBKTkrkcnZy5fDMrUlMUnBOLU7kMjYxNQISyimqGZ5a3iakZUB0A) or [try it online in 2sable](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f//6ML//xOTkjkdnZw5fTMrUlMUnBOLUzkNjYxNQISyimqGZ5a3iakZAA).

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.š
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f7@jC//@VlJQSk5K5HJ2cuXwzK1JTFJwTi1O5DI2MTUCEsopqhmeWt4mpGVAdAA)

**Explanation:**

Builtin to switch the case of all ASCII letters in the (implicit) input-string, after which the result is output implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 42 bytes

Prompts for input. Code adjusted to account for difference between APL+WIN atomic vector and that of Dyalog Classic

```
⎕av[m+∊+/48 ¯48×(⊂m←⎕av⍳⎕)∊¨(⊂⍳26)+¨17 65]
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz0NJJFYFp2r/aijS1vfxELh0HoTi8PTNR51NeUCFYFlH/VuBtKaQBWHVoAkgHwjM03tQysMzRXMTGP/A83h@p/GpZ6YlKzOBaQdnZzBtG9mRWqKgnNicSqYa2hkbAJjKKuoZnhmeZuYmqkDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## YASEPL, 99 bytes

```
=f=1'=l®1=i`1=s¥i,1=w$32=j$65=m$91`2!$j»}3,s,4!j+}2,m,2!)s!m}3,123,3+w!j+6!w-64|2`4$j+w»`3!~!i+}2,l
```

explanation:

```
=f=1'=l®1=i`1=s¥i,1=w$32=j$65=m$91`2!$j»}3,s,4!j+}2,m,2!)s!m}3,123,3+w!j+6!w-64|2`4$j+w»`3!~!i+}2,l         packed
=f                                                                                                          declare F (character that gets printed)
  =1'                                                                                                       get input from user, set result to var1
     =l®1                                                                                                   declare L (length of var1)
         =i                                                                                                 declare I (increment variable)
           `1                                                                               !i }2,l         while I < L ...
             =s¥i,1                                                                                           set S as var1[i]
                   =w$32                                                                                      set W as 32 (switcher)
                        =j$65                                                                                 set J as 65 (second increment variable)
                             =m$91                                                                            set M as 91 (max)
                                  `2          !j }2,m,2                                                       while J < M...
                                    !$j»                                                                        set F to char(J)
                                        }3,s,4                                   `4                             if F == S...
                                                                                   $j+w»                          break out of loop, set F to char(J+W)
                                                                                        `3!~                      print F, and continue
                                                +                                                               else, add 1 to j and loop.
                                                       !)s                                                    set F to S
                                                          !m}3,123,3                    `3                    if M == 123...
                                                                                          !~                    print F, and continue
                                                                    +w                                        else... / add W to M
                                                                      !j+6                                      add 6 to J
                                                                          !w-64                                 subtract 64 from W (making it negative)
                                                                               |2                               go back to point 2
                                                                                              +               once all done, add 1 to I and loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 107 bytes

```lua
o=""s=io.read()for c in s:gmatch"."do if c==c:lower()then o=o..c:upper()else o=o..c:lower()end end print(o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcqxCoMwFEbhV/nNpEseQMggGNuCVLCF4ijxqoGYK1Hbx08R2uEsH8cdfYyshNiUZRmoH9Js5AAD67Hl09LvZhZSDAw7wihlcscfCmm2z@TBiqU0@bGuJ5Hb6E@/i/yAszVYv6ecxTjrDs@rbnUCi1YXdd3B8ZtQNrf7BQUq/YJpSo2pqatH8gU)

---

### Explanation

First time golfing with Lua, and also the first time I'm officially making a proper program with it

We create two strings for our output and input.

```lua
o = ""
i = io.read()
```

Then we use a generator function that yields the matched group expression as the loop repeats (for lack of true understanding, this is what I can come up as a description). Using `.` ensures that `gmatch` returns individual characters.

```lua
for c in s:gmatch"." do
    -- ...
end
```

In the loop we do a test, if the character is lower-case already, we convert it to upper-case. Note that this test automatically lets uncased characters like punctuation and numbers to pass, since they stay the same.

After the conversion, we concatenate the character to the output string.

```lua
if c == c:lower() then
    o = o .. c:upper()
else
    o = o .. c:lower()
end
```

Then we print the output string

```lua
print(o)
```

--

### Full un-golfed code

```lua
o = ""
s = io.read()

for c in s:gmatch"." do
    if c == c:lower() then
        o = o .. c:upper()
    else
        o = o .. c:lower()
    end
end

print(o)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 179 B

This is a full `program` requiring a processor supporting ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” (in particular the `index` function).
Furthermore the implementation must provide uppercase and lowercase characters.

```pascal
program p(input,output);const
A='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';B='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';var
C:char;begin while not EOLn do begin
read(C);write((C+B+A)[index(A+B,C)+1])end end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program swapCase(input, output);
    const
        modernLatinAlphabetMajuscule = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        modernLatinAlphabetMinuscule = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    var
        buffer: char;
    begin
        while not EOLn(input) do
        begin
            { This is equivalent to `buffer ≔ input↑; get(input)`. }
            read(input, buffer);
            { The `+` operater concatenates string and character values. }
            write(
                    output,
                    (
                        { If `index` (below) returns zero
                          (meaning pattern not found)
                          the value of `buffer` is used. }
                        buffer
                        + modernLatinAlphabetMinuscule
                        + modernLatinAlphabetMajuscule
                    )[
                        { The `index` function returns the index of
                          the pattern (second parameter)
                          in the sample (first parameter). }
                        index(
                              modernLatinAlphabetMajuscule
                            + modernLatinAlphabetMinuscule,
                            buffer
                        { In Pascal `string` indices are 1‑based. }
                        ) + 1
                    ]
                )
        end
    end.
```

Note, the `program` does not work correctly if `input` is empty since there is no `EOF` test.

Comment: I believe you do not need test eol as the question only requires printable ascii which exclude the line feed characters from input.

Comment: @tsh `Input` is a `text` file so it consists of lines. A _line_ is a possibly empty sequence of non‑newline characters followed by exactly one line termination symbol.

Comment: But the question only ask about printable ascii. So i believe you may safely assume the file contains only printable ascii, without any line-feeds.

Comment: @tsh No, the special `input` text file is either _empty_ or contains at least one _line_. This _is enforced_ by the processor. That means a missing newline is automatically appended so in Pascal it is _guaranteed_ that you do not receive “degenerate lines”.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
{ụ?ḷ|ụ}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/rh7qX2D3dsrwHStQ@3Tvj/X8nQyFhZRTXDM8vbxNRM6X8UAA)

#### Explanation

We check if a character is invariant by uppercasing, in which case we return the lowercase version, else we return the uppercase.

```
{     }ᵐ     Map for each character:
 ụ?            If the input uppercased is still the input
  ?ḷ           Output is the lowercased input
    |          Else
     ụ         Output is the uppercased input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 78 bytes

78 bytes, it can be golfed more.

```scala
_.map{case c if c.isUpper=>c.toLower;case c if c.isLower=>c.toUpper;case c=>c}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVHRTtswFBWv_YqrDKRECkWjgKZOrdQxEN0ATeoqTWLVdHHcxiy1LfuGgqp-CS-8wAtfND6Cb8B20gweotjnnHt8z713j5ZhgZ2ni2hbqgUaGU2eNybq8oozgjMUEpYtgIxPYe4uMZqZ7cLAGLy9GJERcjZJujCWgqAXlAA7O3CCJmMq4xkIqUsClBnwG-0sHaRKcliQXmMBxC0douXWGZwKS3FgAOIIL1mUQjT4chglaYP6q0M9-QY9EzfO2vt4cj78dfQV2GB09Fbzcfe37Ox5vj694zofNrfy4dX3vf2DSuKBE_HtrweSIExa64DHpWQklARSYBeogbmXm0ge8a10IY6rISW9fn1wKR9Kmm5_-nf-pz1HvfSVwEBMgbWFHWvNTa_P2qRO1YKbz-_pgFV0UNa0Q1a168u6xSFxg8SBcqPKWQ4cWR6GHXpNAbUubptW07AjpuYaDYeFoPz_wgy3ZVEtrFlWe6pMcFwGO4jDotOmyOXs18P1E6ksXPb1e5U-qSXajYYKGdvop2_wB1rLsy5sLtd1vcZ4Ve9i1fJfnfr-vvq_Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 142 bytes

```go
import(q"strings";."unicode")
func f(s string)string{return q.Map(func(r rune)rune{if IsUpper(r){r=ToLower(r)}else{r=ToUpper(r)};return r},s)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZFRSgMxEIbxNacYo4UEtgtqFVFWqG3BqhXRFQQVidtsXdtmt0lWK2Gv4AV8KYKX8CZ6GpNNBV8ymW8mkz9_3j9G-eKrYMmYjThMWSYQyqZFLnWI06nGn6VOm7vfb56RGVZaZmKk8H6IS5El-ZBjitJSJJASBb5KfTCS61IKmIUDVhDXQyTIUnDqFpOl0FdXRcElkdTIKM5P85c6qfhE8Zr8lav95SxZBYpWXtXPyoV-LTjE7toy0WAyUQTA58VSR4XQM5OgudIKIri5iw0ymD0kOADcPuzgKrC529jc4TofZHM-hA5T3OFp_7rXhaR92fPVjc2tluN1_CNr643H_tNJa3tnWbLgKDseO2B7rI7aIWcvoWDQuVWnJ4LgKIou4_ZFbKO1EaW5hPtAw14Ekgn7IV66QSypYUp0aN9IkfXOodUIdOjea6AemRLcmEHzAOxKGjN6K6ye-kjg-gPfTaFykv6L6J11vYSltYuFj78)

One of the few times Go provides a `Map` function, and it's on strings.

Comment: 71 bytes: `func f(s[]byte){for i,c:=range s{if 96<c&&c<123||64<c&&c<91{s[i]^=32}}}`

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 12 Bytes

`s=s.swapcase()`

Comment: Hi there hello! Code golf answers are expected to either be full programs or function submissions. Assuming input in a variable is not an allowed input format for python. Further, the result of `s.swapcase()` needs to be either returned from a function or sent to STDOUT.

Comment: In this case you could just answer `str.swapcase` which is the same byte count

Comment: Is this better @lyxal? I located s to the output.

Comment: Please note that `swapcase` already has an [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/270236/55372).

Comment: No, your edit is not better. It still takes input from a predefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 55 bytes

```
|!II^P[gnsF0*32+~,>]`:sF2$F1-~:s<91[1g>64]:s<123[1g>96]
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7C!II%5EP%5BgnsF0*32%2B%7E%2C%3E%5D%60%3AsF2%24F1-%7E%3As%3C91%5B1g%3E64%5D%3As%3C123%5B1g%3E96%5D&inputs=Mixed%20Case%20123a89)

By design, Rattle does not have many built-ins to encourage more creative problem-solving. This means there is no built-in for checking or changing character case whatsoever. With the current number of bytes, this Rattle code is able to 1) iterate over all characters, 2) check if the character is upper-case or lower-case (implemented from scratch), and 3) swap the character case if this criteria is met.

This code is explained thoroughly because it's probable that a shorter solution exists (with the lack of built-ins for this in mind) - I encourage you to try to beat this code length!

## Explanation

```
|                        get input
 !                       disable implicit output
  I                      split into chars
   I^                    get number of chars
     P                   reset pointer
      [...]`             loop N times, N = number of chars

g                        get the value at the pointer
 n                       convert to ASCII int
  s                      save to memory
   F0                    call local function 0 (returns -1, 0, or 1)
                           (-1 if a-z, 1 if A-Z, 0 otherwise)
     *32                 multiply by 32 (the difference between A-a, B-b, etc.)
        +~               add value in memory
          ,              output character corresponding to ASCII value
           >             move pointer right

:                        start local function 0
 s                       save input (passed implicitly) to memory
  F2                     call local function 2 (returns 1 if a-z, 0 otherwise)
    $                    swap result with value in memory
     F1                  call local function 1 (returns 1 if A-Z, 0 otherwise)
       -~                subtract value in memory (becomes -1 if a-z, 1 if A-Z, 0 otherwise)

:                        start local function 1 (checks if A-Z)
 s                       save input (passed implicitly) to memory
  <91                    check if the value is <91
     [1....]             if <91...
       g                 get the value in memory
        >64              check if the value is >64

:                        start local function 2 (checks if a-z)
 s                       save input (passed implicitly) to memory
  <123                   check if the value is <123
     [1....]             if <123...
       g                 get the value in memory
        >96              check if the value is >96
```